# The previous route/component continous to show until the next route is activated by ResolveFn

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a main app component with two `router-outlet`, one before login and one for after

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!user">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

It all works fine.

The pages after login has resolver, so route is activated only after the data is resolved.

What the problem is, after login until the next route is activated after the `resolveFn` fully resolved, it kept on showing the login page inside of the website.

[image]

You can see in the above image that user is successfully logged in and so the menu on the left started to appear, but the next route is not yet activated because the resolver is still fetching data (see the network tab, one pending request), so until the data is getting fetched it keeps on showing the previous route i.e. `/login` page.

Is there any way I can restrict the `router-outlet` not show login component after login?

Or any standard way to handle this issue?

One idea that I have in mind is to put all the code of `LoginComponent` inside this div, so that once the user is logged in nothing will be shown on login page even if it is selected.

```
<div *ngIf="!user">
</div>
```

But that seems me like a workaround. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: is it possible to add a minimal reproduction of your code using stackblitz ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your app component html:

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!user">
 <app-login></app-login>
</div>
```

Another way you can try would be to naming route for connected and non connect user: Example.

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <router-outlet name="connected"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!user">
  <router-outlet  name="non-connected"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And don't forget to configure your paths by adding `outler` on routes definition side. [Example of this implementation](https://lukeliutingchun.medium.com/angular-introduction-to-named-router-outlet-and-a-hack-for-custom-url-6ca1cd11fd2a).